# Specific code for different branches

Tags: javascript, git, gruntjs, branch

We have a backbone.js application for a number of devices. While most of the code is common for every device there are some parts that are specific for some of them. It can be some js code or some templates.

Currently we have one branch (master) that holds all of the above and a separate branch for every device and every time we merge master to a device branch we have to manually remove everything not related to that branch.

Is there a way to do that automatically? Maybe wrap the specific code parts in a comment and have it removed for unrelated branch?

```
//samsung_platform_code
someJS()...
//samsung_platform_code_end

//panasonic_platform_code
someJS()...
//panasonic_platform_code_end
```

The master branch has to work on all devices, so we have a bunch of if's and case's all over the code.

Are there any plugins for jetBrains php/webStorm, git or maybe that can be achieved with Grunt somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a branch per device could work. However it may quickly become a pain, in particular because the more devices you have, the more merges you'll have to do every time you push consequent changes on `master`.
It seems you're just starting to feel the limits of this workflow.

A simpler workflow could be to use only a single branch (ie: only `master`) and to use [Grunt preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess#grunt-preprocess-): according to its documentation it seems you'll be able to do what you want:

```
// @ifdef SAMSUNG
someJS()...
// @endif

//@ifdef PANASONIC
someJS()...
//@endif
```

Another advantage of this single-branch-workflow, if you're using continuous integration, is that it will be easy to run tests for every devices, at every push on `master`.